# Getting a fragment error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm new to android studio and programming in genral, I have tried many video tutorials and reading through answered questions on this website but can't find an answer, help would be appreciated.

Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d0084 (com.example.hotrod.hotrodsapp:id/content_frame) for fragment FragOne{8f6227a #0 id=0x7f0d0084}

I'm using the navigation drawer template and receiving this error when I try to open a page from the navdrawer in the emulator.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

This is the code for my fragone-

```
public class FragOne extends android.app.Fragment {

View myView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1, container ,false);
    return myView;
}
```

}

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Show us your onCreate() or onCreateView()

Comment: @ApolloSoftware added

Comment: is there any code which you are doing fragment transaction for the fragment FragOne ?

Comment: Including the entire stack trace, and even some context around it from logcat is always useful. The problem is people don't understand whether you are adding the fragment manually (and if so, where's the code?) or adding it from a layout (and if so, where's the layout?).